# Open ground wire causing weird behaviour of combination meter

Tags: wiring, ground

Few months ago, my combination meter suddenly start flicking then all the gauges stop working. After diagnosing it myself with multimeter and with the help of wiring diagram obtained from google search, I think the probable cause is open ground wire, because when i test it, it seems to have no connectivity to the ground at all.

Now my problem is whether I should just pull a new ground wire for the combination meter or find out where the wire break by tracing it through the wire harness. Since I doesn't have professsional tools like wire tracer , I think the work is going to be very messy.

Edit:
After pulling a temporary ground wire to the combination meter, it worked normally, should I pull a new permanent ground wire and left the old wire unfixed or just fix the old wire

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think your first step should be to proof the ground is the issue. You could do that by running a temporary ground wire. Once you have proof this is the issue, you can track down the specific ground through the wire loom of the vehicle. It wouldn't make sense to me to try and track a break in the wire which doesn't exist.

Comment: After running a temporary ground wire for the combination meter, the combination meter worked normally, so the broken ground wire is the cause of problem. What should i do next